# Specify forest while inserting/fetching the document in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

If I have to insert a document in MarkLogic, how can I specify in which forest the document should be stored, using the Java API?

Here is an example where I write data to a MarkLogic database :

```java
// create the client
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
    props.host, props.port, props.writerUser, props.writerPassword,
    props.authType);

// make use of the client connection
TextDocumentManager docMgr = client.newTextDocumentManager();
String docId = "/example/text.txt";
StringHandle handle = new StringHandle();
handle.set("A simple text document");
docMgr.write(docId, handle);
```

If I can store the document by specifying the forest, then I also need to fetch the document with the forest specified.

I think it is possible because I have seen storing and searching within a specific forestId in XQuery. Like so:

insert into a specific forest:

```
xdmp:document-insert(
    $uri as xs:string,$root as node(), 
    [$permissions as element(sec:permission)*], [$collections as xs:string*],      
    [$quality as xs:int?], [$forest-ids as xs:unsignedLong*])
as empty-sequence()
```

search a specific to forest -

```
cts:search(
    $expression as node()*, $query as cts:query?,
    [$options as (cts:order|xs:string)*], [$quality-weight as xs:double?], 
    [$forest-ids as xs:unsignedLong*]) as node()*
```

Please let me know how to do this in the Java API.

Answer (score 1):

Today this is not available via Java Client API.  It will be available in MarkLogic 9.  If you want to try it out in an early access release of MarkLogic 9 you can join the [early access program](https://ea.marklogic.com).  We would love to hear your feedback after trying out this feature.

In MarkLogic 9 you can do this by specifying the forestName to the DatabaseClientFactory:

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
    props.host, props.port, props.writerUser, props.writerPassword,
    props.authType, props.forestName);
```

Then documents written will be written to that forest and searches will only match within that forest.